# How to identify and kill the old process to solve JVM Bind Exception?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I'm trying to run my projects in eclipse but whenever i run my project its showing

```
Address already in use: JVM_Bind Exception.
```

How to solve this one?

Comment: Which environment are you running? Window/Linux/Mac? If its windows check the task manager for the process and kill the process which might not have been shut down.

Comment: I am using windows os

Answer (score 1):

You have another process that uses the same port as your project. Try to identifiy the port and try to find it using netstat -ano  | find ":80" cmd line (if you are a windows user). the "80" is port numbe. That's my best hint because you don't share enought details.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows
 1. Hit Ctrl-alt-delete and look at open programs. Look for java.exe.
 2. From a command window, run netstat -an. Check which ports are in use. You can identify which application is running this way, then close it from the Task Manager.
 3. List item

If you intend to run both JIRA and Confluence on the same machine for trial purposes, you will need to change either of the listening port number from the default (8080). 
If you are using older versions of JBoss, chances are that MS Office or MS OfficeCommunicator are engaging port 1098 and 1099. If you don't want to shut down these tools then your only option is using a different bind address